# How do CSS grid systems save time when implementing designs that aren’t grid-based?

Tags: css, photoshop, twitter-bootstrap, css-frameworks

What CSS grid systems do quickly which we can't do without them?

I work on freelance projects from various resources and the Photoshop file (PSD) i get are not based on grid or not using same grid width and column, gutters. I'm not in direct communications with designers. I only get design files directly from Clients or other freelancers/sub-contractors. **I'm good at making HTML CSS for PSD without using any Grid also with IE compatibility.**

These days twitter bootstrap is being popular in community which is based on 940px width grid and other thing too for button, and jquery plugins.

My question is specifically for using grid. How it can reduce our development time without restricting us on anything compare to our usual method, specially when Designer are on remote locations and I'm directly not connected to them and even I can't force them to use any grid based systems. Some clients are asking me to use twitter bootstrap but the design files they give me are not matching with 940px grid.

Comment: I'm curious what you mean by "our usual method." What is the usual? HTML/CSS doesn't really have an element for grid layouts. You could use `display:table;` but that is difficult to make responsive. You could `float:left; width:50%;` to put things next to each other, or you could make specific `width`s for each column with media queries to make it responsive, which is what Bootstrap does. Personally I find Bootstrap to be more of a hindrance when working with designers that rig everything in Photoshop without understanding Bootstrap, but great when a client just wants you to make up something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the design you’re implementing isn’t based on a layout grid, then a CSS grid system won’t help you at all.

I’ll probably show my lack of design knowledge here, but my understanding is that layout grid specifies a minimum width for layout columns, e.g. 60px, and a width for the gutter (the horizontal space between columns), e.g. 20px. Larger columns are then made up of multiples of the minimum column width and the gutter — e.g. a 4-span column is as wide as four individual layout columns, plus three gutters.

It’s a way to make layouts with different numbers of columns look consistent with each other.

CSS grid systems implement this in CSS for you, so that you don’t have to write any CSS.

- E.g. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#grid-system

You just apply classes to HTML elements. In the case of Twitter Bootstrap’s CSS grid system, to have a 4-span column and and 8-span column next to each other, you use the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">...</div>
    <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>
```

The `<div>`s then get the right widths and gutters, and the right combination of `float`-related code so that they’re laid out as columns. So you get the time savings from not having to write (and debug in various browsers) any layout CSS for individual columns.

But if the *design* you’re implementing doesn’t use a layout grid, then a CSS grid system won’t help you at all, because you’re not implementing a layout grid.

Comment: So it's only good to use Grid based Frameworks when Designer and Developer both think and work in that way

Comment: And other problem with framework is , for one project a year ago I used Blueprint CSS Framework for PSD 2 HTML conversion. Conversion was nice and client was happy but he came back to me after 2-3 days and tell that his back-end developer are struggling to understanding the technique i used to align boxes and many other thing eventually i had to re-coded in normal way.

Comment: “So it's only good to use Grid based Frameworks when Designer and Developer both think and work in that way” — correct, in the same way that you wouldn’t use a jQuery lightbox plugin to implement a drop-down menu.

Comment: With regards to back-end developers understanding CSS frameworks/libraries, I’ve personally only looked at the source of 960.gs, but that took me about 10 minutes to understand after reading it. Obviously I’m comfortable with CSS, but I’d be interested to know what the “normal way” you re-coded your layout in was — what did the back-end developers find easier to understand?

Comment: I took these words from Chris's article "I once did a job where the client wanted everything to be done with YUI, starting with grids. I spent more time learning about YUI and trying to figure out how to stuff an already-designed Photoshop file into it than I did actually sweating the details and focusing on quality. Ultimately we got it done, but the time spent was easily tripled trying to use this framework that I can't imagine was very useful in the end." http://css-tricks.com/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-a-css-framework/

Comment: Right, but my question was about when your client came back to you and said the back-end developers were having trouble understanding the code you built with BluePrint, and how you changed it to make it easier for them to understand.